# Simple front-end call to contract function returns undefined

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat, moralis

Simple contract function call using useWeb3Contract() returns **undefined**.
Here is the front-end code :

```
const { chainId: chainIdHex, isWeb3Enabled, account } = useMoralis()
const purejson = { 31337: ["0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512"] }
const abi = ... //the abi 
const { runContractFunction: runFunction } = useWeb3Contract({
    abi: abi,
    contractAddress: purejson["31337"],
    functionName: "testNumber",
    params: {},
  })
  let simpleNumber
  async function simpleUpdateUI() {
    console.log("updating UI" + (await runFunction())) //returns undefined
  }
```

Contract function I'm calling:

```
function testNumber() public pure returns (uint8){
    return 7;
}
```

Hardhat config:

```
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
    },
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
      chainId: 31337,
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error variable returned by useWeb3Contract that you can use to debug:

```
const { runContractFunction: runFunction, error } = useWeb3Contract({
```

Then just print error.

Comment: Hey, if this is a part of question, then please edit the question and add this to the question.

Comment: It's how I solved my problem.